# How to Escape Double Quote in Multline Literal String

Tags: c#, string, escaping, string-literals

I am building a string of HTML.  I want to have it multiline so that I can read it, but I can't seem to figure out how to escape the double quotes.  I am using `string = @"bla"` for a string literal to allow for the multiline but when I can't seem to use a backslash to escape the double quotes.

Here is what I have...

```
string output;

output = @"<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            th, tr, td { padding-left: 5px; }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=\"2\">";
```

It's getting hung up on the `<td colspan=\"2\">`  Can I not use \ with the literal?  What are my options?

Comment: 1. no harm in adding a + to concatenate it's still legible. 2. Replace the \ with another quote and use double quotes                 var output = @"<html>
                    <head>
                        <style>
                            th, tr, td { padding-left: 5px; }
                        </style>    
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan=""2"" >";

Answer (score 2):

You just use 2 consecutive double-quotes (`""`):

```
string s = @"Porky The Pig said, ""That's all, Folks!""...";
```

But you might want to use a proper templating engine, for instance (but by no means limited to):

- StringTemplate: https://www.stringtemplate.org/
- Handlebars.Net: https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net
- DotLiquid: http://dotliquidmarkup.org/
- Scriban: https://github.com/scriban/scriban

They'll almost certainly be less susceptible to various injection attacks than rolling your own.

Answer (score -2):

You may find it more desirable to create HTML in an HTML file rather than concatenating strings. Try the following:

**Create a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

**VS 2019**:

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Add folder** (name: Html)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **New folder**. Rename to desired name (ex: Html)

**Add HTML file**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the folder you created (ex: Html)
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side, under **Visual C# Items**, click **Web**
- Select **HTML page** (name: HTMLPage1.html)
- Click **Add**
- In Solution Explorer, click HTML page (ex: HTMLPage1.html)
- In Properties Window, set the following property: **Build Action: Embedded Resource**

**Create a class** (name: HelperLoadResource.cs)

**Add the following using statements**:

- `using System;`
- `using System.Text;`
- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Reflection;`

**HelperLoadResource**

**Note**: The following code is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).

```
public static class HelperLoadResource
{
    public static string ReadResource(string filename)
    {
        //use UTF8 encoding as the default encoding
        return ReadResource(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public static string ReadResource(string filename, Encoding fileEncoding)
    {
        string fqResourceName = string.Empty;
        string result = string.Empty;

        //get executing assembly
        Assembly execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //get resource names
        string[] resourceNames = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        if (resourceNames != null && resourceNames.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string rName in resourceNames)
            {
                if (rName.EndsWith(filename))
                {

                    //set value to 1st match
                    //if the same filename exists in different folders,
                    //the filename can be specified as <folder name>.<filename>
                    //or <namespace>.<folder name>.<filename>
                    fqResourceName = rName;

                    //exit loop
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if not found, throw exception
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fqResourceName))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Resource '{filename}' not found.");
            }

            //get file text
            using (Stream s = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fqResourceName))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s, fileEncoding))
                {
                    //get text
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//get HTML as string
string html = HelperLoadResource.ReadResource("HTMLPage1.html");
```

**Resources**:

- [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)